# Get different timezones with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, timezone, date

Im using this clock plugin: http://designxcore.com/stock/CodeCanyon/clock/main/index.html

I have four different clocks on the website I wish to display..
The clocks should display the time in: London, New York, Hong Kong, Tokyo

However, this plugin takes the time that is on a persons local computer.
How can i set it to display the different timezones for the cities i wish to display ?

Comment: I want to display the different timezone - Fx even if a person is in london, there should still be a clock displaying the time in ex: Hong Kong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quite sure this will get you going:

[JS World Clock](http://www.proglogic.com/code/javascript/time/worldclock.php) I don't think it address the your time-zone issues, but as I said, I'll get you going...

BTW: I would for this recommend the use of PHP specifically the [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function!

Good luck!

Comment: @Nicky glad to help!! and glad you're accepting answers!! :) Keep it up!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how can the plugin display four different clocks, but in JavaScript, you can use the Date constructor to create separate date objects for different timezones, all you need is to pass a "proper date string" while initializing, for example:

```
new Date( "HongKong DateTime String" );
new Date( "Tokyo Date Time String" );
```

So, assuming in server side you'll have the information of the current time in those locations, so all you need to do is format that to the date format which JavaScript understands and write them in the page and use accordingly.

For more information you can check out this page:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Hope it helps

Comment: Im not quite sure that i understand? You want me to hardcode the time that is in fx Hong Kong in the string? I want it to take the actual time in Hong Kong

Comment: Ok, for example if you have a PHP page then what you can do is to put something like this in a script block var hkDate = "<?php $hong_kong_date ?>", then pass that "hkDate" string where you are initializing the date like this "new Date( hkDate )"

Answer (score 0):

by using this you can always get your local time converted into a particular timezone

```
 let Accepted_time = new Date();
 const option={ timeZone: 'Asia/Hong_Kong' , hour12:false }

 console.log(Accepted_time.toLocaleTimeString('zh-HK',option))
```